# NSAttributedString multiline giving wrong height?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, nsattributedstring

I want to calculate the height of NSAttributedString Multiline. It is working fine for single line (means it is minus the leading from the height). but if the text is multiline it is giving the same as single line.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *titleParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
titleParagraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.9f;
titleParagraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(TOUNameWidth, MAXFLOAT); 

NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      TOUNameFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                      titleParagraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                      nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: name attributes:attributesDictionary];


CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];

NSLog(@"rect is %f",rect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 8):

As per the documentation of `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` you need to add `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`

> If NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin is not specified, the
>   rectangle’s height will be ignored and the operation considered to be
>   single-line rendering. (Due to a bug, the width is also ignored on iOS
>   6.)